# Template specialization for rvalues

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue

I have a compact set of functions that I use to write arbitrary data to a comma separated values file. It looks something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    out << a << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a, Args... args) {
    out << a << ",";
    log(out, args...);
}

int main()
{
    log(std::cout, 1, "a");
}
```

Which outputs what I would expect:

```
1,a
```

However, when writing strings that have embedded commas the values should be wrapped in quotes. So I want:

```cpp
log(1, "a, b");
```

To output:

```
1,"a, b"
```

*Not*:

```
1,a, b
```

I tried to address this by adding quoting functions that look like this:

```cpp
/* For any old type, just write it out. */
template<typename T>
void quote(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    out << a;
}

/* Specialize for std::string. */
template<>
void quote<std::string>(std::ostream& out, std::string a) {
    if (a.find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

/* Log a single value. */
template<typename T>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a) {
   quote(out, a);
   out << std::endl;
}

/** Log multiple values. */
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a, Args... args) {
    quote(out, a);
    out << ",";
    Log(out, args...);
}
```

If I log the data as an lvalue this works.

```cpp
std::string text {"a, b"};
log(std::cout, 1, text);
```

Produces the expected output:

```
1,"a, b"
```

But passing rvalues does not seem to work.

I tried specializing the quote method for std::string& std::string&& std::string const&, and std::string const&&, but nothing seems to work.

Below is the full set of things I tried:

```cpp
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/* For any old type, just write it out. */
template<typename T>
void quote(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    out << a;
}

/* Output a string wrapped in "'s if it contains a comma. */
template<>
void quote<std::string>(std::ostream& out, std::string a) {
    if (a.find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

/* Output a string wrapped in "'s if it contains a comma. */
template<>
void quote<std::string const>(std::ostream& out, std::string const a) {
    if (a.find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

/* Output a string wrapped in "'s if it contains a comma. */
template<>
void quote<std::string const&>(std::ostream& out, std::string const& a) {
    if (a.find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

/* Output a string wrapped in "'s if it contains a comma. */
template<>
void quote<std::string const&&>(std::ostream& out, std::string const&& a) {
    if (a.find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

/* log a single value. */
template<typename T>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a) {
   quote(out, a);
   out << std::endl;
}

/** log multiple values. */
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T a, Args... args) {
    quote(out, a);
    out << ",";
    log(out, args...);
}


int main()
{
    std::string b { "a, b" };
   
    log(std::cout, 1, b);
    log(std::cout, 1, "c, d");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1,"a, b"
1,c, d
```

Note: For the project I'm working on we're limited to C++11 and boost is not available.

Comment: `Log(out, args...);` ? typo ?

Comment: [OT]: You don't need to use a recursive approach or an overload for `log` starting C++17; just use [a fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold): `template<class T, class ...Args> void log(T&& t, Args&& ... args) { quote(out, std::forward<T>(t)); ((out << ',', quote(out, std::forward<Args>(args))), ...); out << std::endl; }`

Comment: Nice, but this particular project is limited to C++11 (and no access to boost), I'll edit the post to mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your specializations don't work for a value such as `"c, d"` is because its type is `char const*`, not `std::string`. The main `quote` template will be called by default unless the argument type exactly matches one of the specializations. Your example with `std::string b` works because of the `std::string` specialization (and not for example because of the `std::string const&` one).

You could add more specializations, like this for example:

```
template<>
void quote<char const*>(std::ostream& out, char const* a) {
    if (std::string(a).find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    }
    else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}
```

However, I don't think this solves your problem. What you actually want is to handle any case where the argument is *convertible* to a `std::string`.

Also, you probably want to take the arguments by const reference.

You can write the whole thing in one function, provided you are using C++17 (for `if constexpr`):

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T const& a, Args const&... args) {
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>) {
        if (static_cast<std::string const&>(a).find(',') != std::string::npos) {
            out << '"' << a << '"';
        } else {
            out << a;
        }
    } else {
        out << a;
    }
    
    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) > 0) {
        out << ",";
        log(out, args...);
    } else {
        out << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vKaWYoMd4)

Here is a slightly more complex version using a fold expression instead of recursion:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T const& a, Args const&... args) {
    auto quote = [&out](auto const& a) {
        if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(a), std::string>) {
            if (static_cast<std::string const&>(a).find(',') != std::string::npos) {
                out << '"' << a << '"';
            } else {
                out << a;
            }
        } else {
            out << a;
        }
    };

    quote(a);
    ((out << ',', quote(args)), ...);
    out << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/69Wo79Gj3)

Prior to C++17, the same thing can be achieved with tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
void quote(std::ostream& out, T const& a, std::true_type) {
    if (static_cast<std::string const&>(a).find(',') == std::string::npos) {
        out << a;
    } else {
        out << '"' << a << '"';
    }
}

template<typename T>
void quote(std::ostream& out, T const& a, std::false_type) {
    out << a;
}

template<typename T>
void log(std::ostream& out, T const& a) {
   quote(out, a, std::is_convertible<T, std::string>{});
   out << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(std::ostream& out, T const& a, Args&&... args) {
    quote(out, a, std::is_convertible<T, std::string>{});
    out << ",";
    log(out, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4xGae6EK5)

Comment: Actually with C++17, there's no need to write this recursively. Personally I prefer the version using a fold expression: https://godbolt.org/z/zf46fv8PE

Comment: You also may want to go with `static_cast<std::string const&>(a).find(',')` instead of `std::string(a).find(',')` to avoid creating a new string object, if you pass a element that's already a `std::string`.

Comment: Good idea. I added my version of that.